# Need a increasing number of spaces before each line

Tags: java, for-loop

I need this output

```
5   
 4     
  3 
   2 
    1 
     0
```

the Code I have:

```
public static void outputEleven()
{
    System.out.println("");
    for(int x=5; x>=0; x--)
    {   
        System.out.println(x);
        for(int s=0; s<=5; s++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

}
```

The output I'm getting:

```
5
      4
      3
      2
      1
      0
```

Why am I getting this output? How can I get the output desired?

Comment: `for(int s=0; s<=(5-x); s++)`?

Comment: That worked. That was a really simple mistake on my part. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Bit of a warning though, with the logic you have it will print an empty line of spaces after the last number is printed. You  can avoid that by having the space loop before the print loop, you should be able to make it work without much modification.

Comment: @DPabst, Check out my answer  with lesser time complexity and usage of one loop.

Answer (score 2):

In your inner loop, you want to print `i` spaces before printing the value. Something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(5 - i);
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
5
 4
  3
   2
    1
     0
```

**Alternatively**, for the same output, counting backwards like

```
for (int x = 5; x >= 0; x--) {
    for (int s = 0; s < 5 - x; s++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: More loops leads to more complexity, can be better done using System.out.format.